# Multiplication group for $\mathbb Z_n$ modulo $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

By definition:

Let $\mathbb Z^+_n = \{[0],[1],[2],\ldots,[n−1]\}$

$\mathbb Z^+_4 = \{[0],[1],[2],[3]\},$

but

how $\mathbb Z^*_{12}$ is $\{[1],[5],[7],[11]\}$ ?

how $\mathbb Z^*_{7}$ is $\{[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]\}$ ?

Comment: $Z_{12}^*$ is the set of units (invertible elements, which are a group under multiplication) modulo $12$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should distinguish between the additive groups $Z_4$ and

$Z_{12}$, which has $\{[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],...,[11]\}$,

and the multiplicative groups $Z_4^*$, which has $\{[1],[3]\}$, and $Z_{12}^*$, which has $\{[1],[5],[7],[11]\}$.

Those marked with $^*$ have the elements with multiplicative inverses.

**Addendum to answer additional question in comment from OP:**

The elements with multiplicative inverses in the ring $Z_{12}$ are those

whose representatives are relatively prime to $12$, i.e.,  not multiples of $2$ or $3$.

Comment: My question is, how do I find the elements of `Z*12`?

Comment: Since the prime factors of $12$ are $2$ and $3$, find those elements of $\mathbb Z_n$ that are not multiples of $2$ and not multiples of $3$

Comment: @user1787812 The elements whose representatives are relatively prime to 12 make up the multiplicative group of units of $\mathbf{Z}/12\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: `{1,5,7,11}` are list of multiplicative inverses, but not multiplicative groups. Isn't it?

Comment: The set $\{[1],[5],[7],[11]\}$ with multiplication modulo $12$ is a multiplicative group; elements of that set have multiplicative inverses modulo $12$

Answer (score 1):

$\require{cancel}$
\begin{align}
\frac 1 {12} & = \frac 1 {12} & \text{No cancellation occurs here.} \\[6pt]
\frac 2 {12} & = \frac {\cancel2\times1}{\cancel2\times6} = \frac 1 6 \\[6pt]
\frac 3 {12} & = \frac {\cancel3\times 1}{\cancel3\times 4} = \frac 1 4 \\[6pt]
\frac 4 {12} & = \frac{\cancel4\times1}{\cancel4\times3} = \frac 13 \\[6pt]
\frac 5 {12} & = \frac 5 {12} & \text{No cancellation occurs here.} \\[6pt]
\frac 6 {12} & = \frac{\cancel6\times1}{\cancel6\times2} = \frac 1 2 \\[6pt]
\frac 7 {12} & = \frac 7 {12} & \text{No cancellation occurs here.} \\[6pt]
\frac 8 {12} & = \frac{\cancel4\times2}{\cancel4\times3} = \frac 2 3 \\[6pt]
\frac 9 {12} & = \frac{\cancel3\times3}{\cancel3\times4} = \frac 3 4 \\[6pt]
\frac{10}{12} & = \frac{\cancel2\times5}{\cancel2\times6} = \frac 5 6 \\[6pt]
\frac{11}{12} & = \frac{11}{12} & \text{No cancellation occurs here.} \\ {}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

For any $n$ (positive integer), those elements of $G = \mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ whose representatives are realatively prime to $n$ make up the multiplicative group of units of $G$, denoted $G^\times$. You can compare this with your example $n = 12$, which are, as J.W. Tanner wrote, not multiples of $2$ or $3$.

The additive group $G$ gets its additive (abelian) structure from the rules for modular arithmetic (if two sums are congruent modulo $n$, then they are equal in $G$, and similarly for products).

Comment: How does it work using clock arithmetic for both addition & multiplication group? in the sense, for Z+4, element 9 mean 1 after 9 single steps in the hour clock

Comment: @user1787812 Clock arithmetic really depends on being additive, since you an always add an hour to get around the clock (or subtract to go back). To my knowledge there is no such natural analogy for the group of units.